# How to move a word to the beginning of a line using C#

Tags: c#, string, file-io

Have some troubles with my C# homework

Here the task: "Text file L4_16T.txt contains text. The delimiters are known. Move each longest word that start with capital (uppercase) letter, to the beginning of the line with delimiters behind. Write modified text to a separate result file Results.txt. Prepare analysis file Analysis.txt using table format (2 columns): line number, word that start with a capital (uppercase) letter"

For example, in the text I have string `Lorem Ipsum including versions of PageMaker`.
In this string the longest word that start with uppercase letter is `PageMaker`.
And I need to move this word on the beginning of the string, and take `PageMaker Lorem Ipsum including versions of` in the result.

But I have no idea how to move whole word to the beginning of the line.
If somebody know how to do that, please write your ideas.
Thank all of you very much;)

P.S.
For this work I can use `Regex(Regular Expressions)`

Code of the programm:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab_4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        const string strFile = "Text.txt";
        const string resFile = "Results.txt";
        const string aFile = "Analyz.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Process();
        }

        static void Process()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(resFile, true))
                {
                    string line;
                    char[] delimitars = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
                    
                @k1:
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line == ""){ goto @k1;}
                        string LongestWord = TheLongestWord(line, delimitars);
                        writer.WriteLine(LongestWord);
                        Console.WriteLine(LongestWord);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static string TheLongestWord(string line, char[] delimitars)
        {

            string[] words = line.Split(delimitars);
            string longest = "";
            int length = 0, k = 0;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < words[k].Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (words[k].Length >= length)
                        {
                            if (Char.IsUpper(words[k][0]))
                            {
                                longest = words[k];
                                length = words[k].Length;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return longest;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if there are two strings with first character in uppercase but having the same length?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in two steps.

First replace the given substring with empty string and then insert that string to the beginning of this string.

Code should be like this.

```
str = str.Replace(subString, string.Empty);
str = str.Insert(0, subString);
```

Here I am assuming that you are aware of whether you have duplicate substring or not.